# Saving an image/video on the the disk on a NodeJS server and the reference to the MongoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am looking to find out a best way to save an image/video on the the disk on a NodeJS server and the reference to the MongoDB. I will also need to do streaming on the video. Any ideas? Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

install  formidable using npm
    //model

```
'use strict';

const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const DoctorSchema = new Schema({
fname: {type: String, required: true},
registrationNo: {type: String},
gender: { type: String},
 //to save image's url
img: {type:String},
 });
const DocModel = mongoose.model('DocModel', DoctorSchema);
module.exports = DocModel;


  //route

 const express = require('express'),
 mongoose = require('mongoose');

const Doctor = mongoose.model('DocModel');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var formidable = require('formidable');
var fs = require('fs');

const Router = express.Router();


 //route to post 
 Router.post('/DoctorRegistration', (req, res) => {
    //json object to save in database
     var doc = new Doctor();
   //declare variable to store other field values
     var user = {};
     var form = new formidable.IncomingForm();
     form.parse(req, function (err, fields, files) {
    //assign field values to user 
     user = JSON.parse(fields.user);
     //path to save image
     var newpath = "";
     //check whether file is null
     if (files.file != null) {
          var oldpath = files.file.path;
         //save image in disk
         newpath = './public/assets/docImg/' + user.fname+'.jpg';
          fs.rename(oldpath, newpath, function (err) {
              if (err) throw err;


         });
        //assign image path to save in database
        doc.img = newpath;
    }
    doc.fname = user.fname;
    doc.registrationNo = user.registrationNo;
    doc.gender = user.gender;
    //save object in database
    doc.save(function (err) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err.message);
            res.json({success: false, message: 'User information 
            already exsits'});
        }
        else {
            console.log(doc);
            res.json({success: true, message: "user created"});

         }
      });

   });


});
```